# Second row of image gallery

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make an image gallery for a 3D prototyping project I did a while ago. Everything seems like it should be fine but the second row of the gallery is shifted to the right and I'm unsure why.

Here is the HTML

```
<div id="thumbDiv" style="width: 60%; margin-left: 20%;">
        <img src="phone1.jpg" id="phone1">
        <img src="phone2.jpg" id="phone2">
        <img src="phone3.jpg" id="phone3">
        <img src="phone4.jpg" id="phone4">
        <img src="phone5.jpg" id="phone5">
        <img src="phone6.jpg" id="phone6">
</div>
```

And here is the CSS

```
#thumbDiv img{
    width: 30%;
    padding: 5px;
    float: left;
    }
```

This is how it comes out
[Phone Gallery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9fqR.png)
Any thoughts?

Comment: add display:block; to img

Comment: there's not enough code here to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know where your problem is but it works fine on my chrome browser. Maybe check the version of chrome and the languages your writing with.(html5 and css3)

```css
#thumbDiv img {
            width: 30%;
            padding: 5px;
            float: left;
        }
```

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div id="thumbDiv" style="width: 60%; margin-left: 20%;">
    <img src="https://i.ebayimg.com/thumbs/images/g/fmgAAOSwNRdX2tiA/s-l225.jpg" id="phone1">
    <img src="https://i.ebayimg.com/thumbs/images/g/fmgAAOSwNRdX2tiA/s-l225.jpg" id="phone2">
    <img src="https://i.ebayimg.com/thumbs/images/g/fmgAAOSwNRdX2tiA/s-l225.jpg" id="phone3">
    <img src="https://i.ebayimg.com/thumbs/images/g/fmgAAOSwNRdX2tiA/s-l225.jpg" id="phone4">
    <img src="https://i.ebayimg.com/thumbs/images/g/fmgAAOSwNRdX2tiA/s-l225.jpg" id="phone5">
    <img src="https://i.ebayimg.com/thumbs/images/g/fmgAAOSwNRdX2tiA/s-l225.jpg" id="phone6">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```